# Grep access on maillog for non root

Tags: centos, permissions, sudo

I would like to grant a specific (regular) user `grep` access on my maillogs (`/var/log/maillog*`).

I'm not prepared to change the log permissions, as they should remain `root`-only, so I think the preferred solution would be via `sudoers`.

Also: I want to grant as little other permissions as possible, ideally the user just has access to the maillog (and the rotated files).

Eg:

```
username ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/grep
```

Allows that user to basically `grep` on any file on the system, which is something I'd like to avoid.

What is the best solution here?
FYI: It doesn't need to be `grep` per se: the user just needs read access to the maillogs and will probably only use `grep` to access them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an acl on the file(s) to grant read permission to user

```
setfacl -m user:grepuser:r /var/log/maillog*
```

This as the advantage of allowing the user to use any tool that they wish.

This is also logrotate safe for maillog*

Comment: what would the `-m` option do normally? It appears unsupported on centos

Comment: @Blizz which version of CentOS? It works fine, is supported and documented on C6 <edit> and C7.

Comment: It's 7.1, but my bad, specified the argument wrong. It works perfectly and it's the best possible option for me. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it's logrotate-safe, or I'm missing something here. But even if I'm right, the command can be run from logrotate as a workaround.

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz you may be right, I thought I had run `logrotate -f ...` after I had set the acl go test  but I wasn't well caffinated at the time.... As you also note adding a postrotate command to the logrotate config is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you know what specific strings the users will be searching for and the specific files they'll be checking using `sudo` is not a good solution for this.  If you create a rule like this:

```
blizz ALL=root NOPASSWD: /bin/grep * /var/log/maillog*
```

The user will be able to run commands like this:

```
grep root /etc/shadow /var/log/maillog
grep = /root/my.cnf /var/log/maillog
```

They'll be able to read any file on the system.  You can find more information about this issue here:

http://blog.csnc.ch/2012/10/dangerous-sudoers-entries-part-4-wildcards/

If you know what strings and files the user will be checking you could define separate rules for each scenario.  For example:

```
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOGA = /bin/grep 'Connection refused' /var/log/maillog
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOGB = /bin/grep 'Connection refused' /var/log/maillog.1
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOGC = /bin/grep 'imap-login' /var/log/maillog
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOGD = /bin/grep 'imap-login' /var/log/maillog.1
blizz ALL=root NOPASSWD: MAILLOGA, MAILLOGB, MAILLOGC, MAILLOGD
```

However, this can be cumbersome and can result in an overly large sudo configuration.

Alternatively, instead of `grep` you could grant them access to the files via the `more` command, then they could search the files interactively:

```
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOG = /bin/more /var/log/mailllog
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOG1 = /bin/more /var/log/mailllog.1
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOG2 = /bin/more /var/log/mailllog.2
Cmnd_Alias  MAILLOG3 = /bin/more /var/log/mailllog.3
blizz ALL=root NOPASSWD: MAILLOGA, MAILLOGB, MAILLOGC, MAILLOGD
```

However this doesn't allow the user to keep a history of their searches (e.g. `.bash_history`) or create their own scripts or aliases for searches.  Plus if you have log rotation in place they won't be able to parse the compressed logs.

<sup>Note: **Do not** grant sudo access to the `less` command.  A user could break out of the process, for example running `!/bin/bash` in `less` would give them root access to the system.</sup>

Another option is to have rules for them to `cat` the files so they can pipe them to `grep` as their heart sees fit. For example:

```
sudo cat /var/log/maillog | grep "anything can go here"
```

In the end the simplest, and likely the best solution, is to grant them read access to the logs by changing the permissions on the log files. You could do something like this:

```
groupadd logcheck
chgrp logcheck /var/log/maillog*
chmod g+r /var/log/maillog*
useradd -G logcheck blizz
```

And then they can use any tool they want to analyze the files (e.g. `grep`, `zgrep`, `less`, `more`, `view`, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some really good idea and a lot of things mention fall in line with what I thought before I posted the question. I just don't want to have to modify too much stuff because then it'll be harder to figure out why things stop working. `setfacl` is just a lot simpler.

Comment: Since the files are owned and written to by root it's perfectly safe to change the group ownership.  Setting an ACL works just as well, but it requires that the file system be tuned or mounted with the `acl` option, so make sure that is in place.

Answer (score 3):

This should work as expected in *sudoers* file:

```
%users  ALL= /bin/cat /var/log/mail.log
%users  ALL= /bin/cat /var/log/mail.err
```

(log paths from Ubuntu, change if necessary)

Using a generic, output-only tool like *cat* is simple and secure. You won't have to permit and limit specific options as with *grep* directly in sudoers. It will also allow filtering of the logs with any *grep-or-not* tool, ie. *awk*, *sed*.

Not sure how *sudo* is configured in CentOS, but if it prompts for a password of **calling** user (not of **target** user), I'd avoid using **NOPASSWD**. This can be a security advantage if any hostile party gets an access to user's account, not knowing user's password.

Comment: That is not secure.  That sudo rule would allow them to run commands like this: `/bin/cat /var/log/mail. /etc/shadow /root/my.cnf`

Comment: You seem to be right. But I remember it working a similar way in the past, I must be missing a detail here... I will edit the answer.